# How can I set the STL implementation in CMake?

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, clang, libc++

I'm interested in trying out clang, for its static analysis capabilities. I'm currently working on a project in c++, running on ubuntu 11.04. One problem with clang is that it can't work with libstdc++ 4.4 [unless I patch it](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html). I don't want to mess with the libstdc++ source for what might be a temporary foray into clang.

The alternative is to use libc++ instead of libstdc++. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find help online for using alternative STL implementations from CMake.

What do I write in my CMakeLists.txt file to tell CMake to use libc++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generally speaking you have to remove the std include from your include path and stop clang from linking with stdlib then you manually include the other libraries as CMake libraries and then you also add the include path.

Do you have libc++ installed?
According to the [libcxx homepage](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) libcxx currently isn't officially supported on linux.

clang is widely argument compatible with gcc thus you should be able to pass `clang -nostdlib -nostdinc`

However you don't necessarily need to build your own libc. You can also build the compiler from sources (trunk) and it will most likely support libstdc++. (I just got it working on Fedora15).

The [Getting Started](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) page of clang is a good resource!

```
BLD=$(pwd)/llvm
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk llvm
cd llvm/tools
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk clang
cd ../.. # back to where you started
cd llvm/projects
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/compiler-rt/trunk compiler-rt
cd ../.. # back to where you started
mkdir build # for building without polluting the source dir
cd build
../llvm/configure --enable-optimize --disable-assertions --prefix /usr/local
make -j8 # adjust to the number of cores or cores times 2
```

The clang binary then resides in `${BLD}/Release/bin/`. if you decide to do a `make install` they should be copied to `/usr/local/bin/`.
Thus you can then pass CMake the following parameters:

```
cd your_source_dir_here 
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${BLD}/Release/bin/clang++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=${BLD}/Release/bin/clang
```

Comment: Whoops; I had assumed that libc++ is available for linux, having seen this blog post of a guy who made it work (http://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/10/16/llvm-clang-libc-linux/). If it isn't officially supported by the authors, however, I'm not sure I'm willing to make the switch anymore. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: @SuperElectric ah thanks for the link. looks interesting to me however running your own libc in a linux distribution can be very painful.

Comment: @SuperElectric I just updated my answer because you most likely don't require a modified libc++